# Personalizar mensajes de respuesta para BadRequest en API Web Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Intento personalizar la respuesta de mi API cuando tengo el caso 400 BadRequest.
El modelo de respuesta debería quedar así:

```
{
"status":"FAILED",
"status_message":"Aquí quisiera mostrar la validación del ModelState."
}
```

En resumen quisiera poder personalizarlo con esos dos campos, en el caso del campo  "status_message" debería contener el array de la validación ModelState.
Ejemplo:

```
 {
  "status":"FAILED",
  "status_message": {
    "request.id": [
        "Campo requerido, <el mensaje que responde la validación de los atributos>"
    ]
  }
}
```

Como saben, por defecto al retornar BadRequest(ModelState), lo muestra muy parecida la estructura pero la verdad no se como personalizar esto.
Si tienen alguna idea, por favor me ayudan. He buscado en la web algún modo de personalizar esto, pero no he logrado el resultado esperado.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: protected internal virtual BadRequestErrorMessageResult BadRequest(string message); Tambein ModelState.AddError("Key","Descripción") --> Pero no es realmente lo que necesito. Incluso trate de usar códigos de ejemplo aplicados para .Net Core pero aún no lo consigo. https://forums.asp.net/t/2171590.aspx?How+to+return+custom+bad+request+response+in+asp+net+core+API https://dzone.com/articles/customizing-automatic-http-400-error-response-in-a .

Comment: Estoy realizando APIs para poder integrarme con Mercado Libre. https://developers.mercadoenvios.com/es_ar/authorization -> Ellos solicitan estructuras especificas de respuesta para la integración.

Comment: Prueba con esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/25829857/4573476 Me sirvió en algunos proyectos

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero en mis API de .Net hago eso con el NegotiatedContentResult.

```
class Request
{
        [JsonProperty("request.id")]
        public string[] request { get; set; }
}

return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
        {
            status = "FAILED",
            status_message = new Request
            {
                request = new string[] { "Campo requerido, <el mensaje que responde la validación de los atributos>" }
            }
        });
```

Donde error es un objeto que se serializa en JSON. Asi puedes darle la estructura que quieras a la respuesta.

Esto lo probé en .net 4.8 y sale exactamente lo que quieres.

Comment: @bsese tienes algún ejemplo, que pueda formar ese tipo de estructura. Son dos Campos que requiero mostrar. status y status_message. Donde status_message contenga todos los errores que se encontró en la validación. Pero es obligatorio que contengan esos nombres(status, ststus_message). Por favor si puedes adjunta tu ejemplo completo. Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo tienes. Las propiedades con el punto te obligan a crear una clase para poder utilizar el atributo JsonProperty de NewtonSoft. Dependiendo de la versión de .net que uses, igual necesitas otro atributo, pero el ejemplo es el mismo entiendo yo.

Comment: Comprendo, por lo que entiendo yo tendría que asignarle el mensaje a cada validación. No hay forma de que se rescate la validación por defecto que tiene el campo. Te cuento que mi modelo de request tienes más de 60 campos(entonces cada campo tiene 1 o más atributos, ya sea de required, range, maxlenghth, etc), es por ello que el return BadRequest(ModelState) lo retorna de manera automática. Pero de todas maneras muchas gracias, en base a tu respuesta trataré de armar el response.

Comment: En el bindingContext.ModelState deberías tener los mensajes de validación, no sé si eso te serviría

Comment: Hola @bsebe, llevo días intentando obtener esas validaciones completas, con el ejemplo que me indicaste logré formar el response requerido, pero el problema es que intente recorrer todos los errores del modelstate y no logro obtener todos. Como debería aplicar bindingContext.ModelState, lo agregó en el status_message? Por fa, si logras obtener todas las validaciones del model, indícame como lo haces. Como te dije, mi request tiene muchos campos e incluso tienen el mismo nombre de campo, ejemplo: request.city.id , request.id, request.contact.id, etc.